# How best to distinguish words based on the letters they contain

Tags: combinatorics

In a spreadsheet, I have a column with a few hundred words that each are made up of $7$ different letters. For example, `ABDOMEN` and `CHEEKBONE` are on the list (duplicate letters are fine).

My goal is to group words that have the same set of $7$ letters, for instance `ABDOMEN` and `BEMOANED` should be grouped together.

To do this, I thought of using powers of $2$ to give each word a "score". If a word has at least one `A`, I add $2^0=1$ to its score. If a word has at least one `B`, I add $2^1=2$ to its score, and so on until I add $2^{25}=33,554,432$ to the score of a word with at least one `Z`. Under this system, the only way for two words to have the same score is if they have the same letters.

So, problem solved, except now I am wondering if I needed to use numbers as large as $2^{25}$? Could I have accomplished the same goal with smaller point values attached to each letter, especially considering that each word is guaranteed to be made of exactly $7$ distinct letters? I only need to avoid the possibility of two different sets of $7$ letters having the same point total.

Here is where I am stuck. I have tried thinking of a simpler version: what if I had words with $3$ distinct letters and the alphabet was only `ABCDEFG`?

I know there are $\binom{7}{3}=35$ different sets of $3$ distinct letters that can be made. However I can't see how this information might be useful for coming up with a formula to assign point values to words.

**EDIT:** I realized this is a variation of the subset-sum problem, namely: in a set of $26$ distinct positive integers, how can I guarantee any $7$ of them will have a unique sum? I know the powers of $2$ work (as would powers of any integer greater than $2$). I am wondering about making the $26$ numbers as small as possible.

The Fibonacci numbers $\{1,2,3,5,8,...\}$ seem like they may be decent starting point. But there are multiple $3$-element subsets that have the same sum, e.g. $1+2+55=3+21+34=58$.

I think (but am not sure) this problem is alleviated if you use the "Tribonacci" numbers $\{1,2,4,7,13,...\}$, where each is the sum of the three previous. I don't know for sure, but I suspect it is likely that there are multiple $4$-element subsets that have the same sum.

So my conjecture is if you extend this to the "Six-bonacci" (or whatever they're called) numbers, where each is the sum of the six previous and the first few are $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,63,125,...\}$, then perhaps no two $7$-element subsets would have the same sum. The $26$th term is $28,261,168$ which is somewhat less than $2^{25}$.

I put a bounty in hopes that someone can confirm or deny my conjecture, and/or point out some information on the subset sum problem that is relevant to this particular question.

Comment: There are $\binom {26}7=657800$  possible sets of $7$ distinct letters.  $\log_2$ of that is $≤20$ so you could get by with smaller than $2^{25}$.  You could order the options lexicographically, though determing the value of some random selection might be inconvenient.

Comment: Why do you care about the size of the numbers? $2^{25}$ is tiny as far as your spreadsheet is concerned and you will find it even more painful than what you have done so far to use a more succinct encoding.

Comment: I figured I can do slightly better, by making the point value for each letter from `H` through `Z` equal to one more than the sum of the $7$ previous letters. Under that system the value of `Z` is a bit over $31$ million. @Rob Arthan I have merely been curious about this for a little while and wanted to see what wisdom MSE could provide.

Comment: If you want my words of wisdom, my advice would be to choose between (1) this is something I only needed to do once and I have a solution that works (so stick with what you have) and (2) this is something that I need to do again and again and I need a production quality solution (so you may need to use a better programming tool than a spreadsheet).

Comment: And $2^{25}= 33554432$ so close by ...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to just split up the words into individual letters and sort that, use that as a key. Now sort the mess by keys, thus grouping together sets of anagrams.

Comment: That may be not so easy if (as the OP has done) you choose to implement this in spreadsheet language.

Comment: @RobArthan If you are working in Excel, it's possible to write a user-defined function in VBA which takes a string as input and returns the sorted version of the string.

Comment: I am well aware of Visual Basic. When I wrote "spreadsheet language", I meant the facilities that spreadsheets offer at their surface HCI, without digging into the horrors that lie underneath.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of possible "words" is given by noting that you can have:

- ${26 \choose 7} = 657800$ choices of 7 different letters
- ${26 \choose 6} = 230230$ choices of 6 different letters, plus one duplicate
- ${26 \choose 5} = 65780$ choices of 5 different letters, with two duplicates (same or different, e.g. ABCDEEE or ABCDDEE)
- ...
- ${26 \choose 1} = 26$ choices of 1 letter repeated 7 times

giving a total of $971711$ total possibilities, which is distinctly smaller than the $2^{26} - 1 = 67108863$ values you'd have with your base-2 encoding.

As to how you could assign those not-quite-a-million indexes efficiently, that might be a trickier problem. It would probably still be easiest to just rearrange the word in alphabetical order without duplicates and sort by that.

Alternatively, depending on your implementation, it might be easiest to use some kind of heuristic to group or sort the words that reduces the work required to look for matches - for example, you could use some kind of [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) that is guaranteed to keep matches together but will also filter out *most* but not all non-matches. A very quick function might be something like "take A = 0, B = 1, ... Z = 25 and calculate the total value of the word", which would put ACT near CAT and EFM but not near ZOO.

Answer (score 0):

Based on vonbrand's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230692/533556), you could use the following VBA script in MS-Excel (using functions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087596) and [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/114780-get-unique-characters-only-in-string-or-cell/&postID=839851#post839851)):

```
Private Function UNIQUECHARS(chtxt As String)
    Dim x, i As Long
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        x = Split(StrConv(Replace(chtxt, " ", ""), 64), Chr(0))
        For i = 0 To UBound(x) - 1
            .Item(x(i)) = Empty
            Next
            UNIQUECHARS = Join(.keys, "")
    End With
End Function

Private Function sortletter(rng As Range)
    If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim srtArr() As String
    Dim i&, j&, k&
    ReDim srtArr(1 To Len(rng))
    srtArr(1) = Mid(rng, 1, 1)
    For i = 2 To UBound(srtArr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(srtArr)
            If srtArr(j) = "" Then
                srtArr(j) = Mid(rng, i, 1)
                Exit For
            ElseIf IIf(Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1)) > 96, Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1)) - 32, Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1))) <= IIf(Asc(srtArr(j)) > 96, Asc(srtArr(j)) - 32, Asc(srtArr(j))) Then
                For k = UBound(srtArr) To j + 1 Step -1
                    srtArr(k) = srtArr(k - 1)
                Next k
                srtArr(j) = Mid(rng, i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    sortletter = Join(srtArr, "")
End Function

Public Function process(rng As Range)
    process = UNIQUECHARS(sortletter(rng))
End Function
```

An MS-Excel sheet with the VBA script implemented can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cB8TRNZvP19HplizD74lfRUpezHw9Xwc?usp=sharing) (note that Google Sheets does not support VBA scripts and you may need to download the file [**at your own risk**]).

Suppose cells `A1` and `B1` contain two strings. Then, the two strings can be grouped together (according to your criteria) *if and only if* `exact(process(A1), process(B1))` returns `TRUE` (using the aforementioned VBA script).